# Outlook Interop exception - displaying new mailitem

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

Trying to automatically generate a mail message via Outlook -

Added a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook 14.0.0.0

It works on a Win 8/Office 2013 PC, but fails with the following exception on Win 7/Office 2010.

Code:

```
Application outlookApp = new Application();
MailItem message = (MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
message.Subject = "subject";
message.Display(message);
message.HTMLBody = "body" + message.HTMLBody; //to get default signature
```

The exception is:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type     'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application'. This
>   operation failed because the    QueryInterface call on the COM
>   component for the interface with IID
>   '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following
>   error: Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D
>   (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)).

Comment: The exception is giving a lot of info on how to resolve it.  Did you look up anything on (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)?

Answer (score 0):

Solution ended up being:

http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/support/support_gsyncit_2013.shtml

Lync 2013 was installed on top of Office 2010.  This adds a registry entry to HKCR\TypeLib{00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}.

Subkey to that registry entry will be different numbered folders, indicating version numbers of Office installed.  (9.4 in this case, indicates 2010, 9.5 indicates 2013).  Once the version number not consistent with the version of Outlook was deleted, it was resolved.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon here. Please summarize the link.